# Adding navigation links on custom post type slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, custom-post-type, testimonials

I'm working on a Wordpress theme from scratch. I have a few sections, one of them showing a video and some testimonials. I've managed to construct (like this: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-rotating-testimonials-in-wordpress/) a nice dynamic testimonial slider using custom post types (where each testimonial is a post) and a script that hide and show each post, making a simple but interesting transition.

Now I need to add a Carousel-like navigation under the slider (with those nice little dots). The problem is: I've tried many solutions but none of them worked. Can someone shine a light for me?

Here is the code I'm using to display the loop of the custom posts:

```
<div class="depo-wrap">
   <div class="depoimentos">
   <?php
      $args = array( 'post_type' => 'testimonial', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      $data = get_post_meta( $loop->post->ID, 'testimonial', true );
      static $count = 0;

      if ($count == "1") { ?>
         <div class="slide" style="display: none;">
            <div class="citacao"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
            <div class="info-pessoal"><?php echo $data[ 'nome-pessoa' ]; ?><span> | </span><?php echo $data[ 'local-origem' ]; ?></div>
            <div class="cargo"><?php echo $data[ 'cargo' ]; ?></div>
         </div>
      <?php } else { ?>
         <div class="slide">
            <div class="citacao"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
            <div class="info-pessoal"><?php echo $data[ 'nome-pessoa' ]; ?><span> | </span><?php echo $data[ 'local-origem' ]; ?></div>
            <div class="cargo"><?php echo $data[ 'cargo' ]; ?></div>
         </div>

    <?php 
       $count++; } 
       endwhile; 
       endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the script that makes everything work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.depoimentos .slide');
  setInterval(function(){
    $('.depoimentos .slide').filter(':visible').fadeOut(1000,function(){
      if($(this).next('.slide').size()){
        $(this).next().fadeIn(1000);
      } else {
        $('.depoimentos .slide').eq(0).fadeIn(1000);
      }
    });
  }, 15000); 
});
```

**TL;DR:** I have this code here and I'm trying to add some of those Carousel-like bullets, or even some next/prev buttons. I just want to add a navigation to this testimonial slide that I've created with custom post types in Wordpress.

Comment: Just some comments: your post is too long, with a lot of unnecessary information (about your project etc...). Best value for StackOverflow is simple question focused on problem. The great thing you can do, is create a minimal problem and create something like JSFiddle, so we can easy access to your problem.

Comment: @areim Oh, sorry about that! I've accepted your edit! :)

Comment: Hello. Is there a reason you're not using the bootstrap carousel itself?

Comment: @Enrico The project is not using the Bootstrap framework... :/

Comment: I don't know about your specific environment, but you can easily include some bootstrap functionality without breaking other components.
You can, of course, create the slider functionality from scratch, but that will surely take more time.

Comment: @Enrico I'm going to try that!

Comment: Excuse me: trying to add bootstrap or start from scratch?

Comment: @Enrico I'm adding Bootstrap to use the Carousel funcionality. It's working so far -- I just have to make some tweaks and I think everything will work perfectly! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Your welcome,ask if you need more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the Bootstrap Carousel worked (thanks @Enrico)! Here's the code with some modifications:

```
<div id="carousel-depoimentos" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="1000">
   <div class="carousel-inner depoimentos">
      <?php
         $args = array( 'post_type' => 'testimonial', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
         $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
         if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
         $data = get_post_meta( $loop->post->ID, 'testimonial', true );
      { ?>

   <div class="item active">
      <div class="citacao"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
      <div class="info-pessoal"><?php echo $data[ 'nome-pessoa' ]; ?><span> | </span><?php echo $data[ 'local-origem' ]; ?></div>
      <div class="cargo"><?php echo $data[ 'cargo' ]; ?></div>
   </div>

   <?php 
      }
      endwhile; 
      endif; 
      wp_reset_postdata();
   ?> 

   <?php
      $args = array( 'post_type' => 'testimonial', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'offset' => 1 );
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      $data = get_post_meta( $loop->post->ID, 'testimonial', true );
   { ?>

   <div class="item">
      <div class="citacao"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
      <div class="info-pessoal"><?php echo $data[ 'nome-pessoa' ]; ?><span> | </span><?php echo $data[ 'local-origem' ]; ?></div>
      <div class="cargo"><?php echo $data[ 'cargo' ]; ?></div>
   </div>

   <?php 
      }
      endwhile; 
      endif; 
      wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>
   </div>                       
</div>
```